# csv.writer with QUOTE_NONE and escapechar=' ' results into double spaces

Tags: python, csv

### Using csv.writer with QUOTE_NONE and escapechar options:

In various examples the space is used for escapechar without questioning: `escapechar=' '`.
However:
**When string data with spaces is written, double spaces are stored in the output file.**

In the manual (https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) it is explained that:

> csv.QUOTE_NONE Instructs writer objects to never quote fields. When
> the current delimiter occurs in output data it is preceded by the
> current escapechar character. If escapechar is not set, the writer
> will raise Error if any characters that require escaping are
> encountered.

So avoiding an escapechar is not accepted.

### Question:

What is a preferred character to avoid unwanted output?
My understanding would be some character that will never occur..
So I don't get it.

### Example code:

```
import csv
lines = [['first line one'],['line 2.0'], ['and; a third line']]

#Example resulting into a double space:
with open('afile_space.csv','w', newline='') as myfile:
    wr = csv.writer(myfile, delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, escapechar=' ')
    for line in lines:
        wr.writerow(line)
#result:
# first  line  one
# line  2.0
# and;  a  third  line

#Example resulting into a double dot for numbers:
with open('afile_dot.csv','w', newline='') as myfile:
    wr = csv.writer(myfile, delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, escapechar='.')
    for line in lines:
        wr.writerow(line)
#result:
# first line one
# line 2..0
# and; a third line

#Example with dotcomma:
with open('afile_dotcomma.csv','w', newline='') as myfile:
    wr = csv.writer(myfile, delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, escapechar=';')
    for line in lines:
        wr.writerow(line)
#result:
# first line one
# line 2.0
# and;; a third line
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? CSV format on disc is a mildly encoded format - usually , to separate the fields, field values which include the separator are usually quoted with “, and where the “ ocurrs in a field value it is escaped so the occurrence isn’t seen as the end of the field. If you want a raw format where the “fields” are output literally then maybe don’t use `csv` but write the strings directly to file - but then it’s not CSV format.

Comment: @barny
thank you for your valuable suggestion. Correct I prefer raw format and from your explanation I understand its better to avoid csv.
In addition, I've noticed when using dialect='excel' option the output is also without quotes. So apparently this is not so stringent? (although I don't consider Microsoft as a good guidance here)

Comment: Who knows. If you want raw though then don’t use `csv` seems the simplest advice.